# "He had me do this" vs "He had me doing this" vs "He had my doing this"

Tags: grammatical-case, gerund-vs-infinitive, causative-verbs, gerund-phrases, possessive-vs-oblique

I know this example sounds awkward, but it’s obviously grammatically incorrect to say "me being here" in sentences like this one:

1. He said **me being here** was wonderful.

That instance of *me being* should be *my being* because we need to use *being* as a gerund phrase so that it can be the subject of the verb *was* and so conform to the grammatical structure of Subject–Verb≠Complement.

But what about in this second example?

2. If he had **my doing** (of) this from the beginning, we would have succeeded.

Because if you say it this way:

3. If he had **me do** this from the beginning, we would have succeeded.

Now there seems to be a conflict of *had* and *do* because both are verbs. Can someone explain, please?

Here is the  [NY Times grammar example:](http://afterdeadline.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/05/29/one-of-those-things-again/?_r=0) the After Deadline blog posting of 2012-05-29:

> Aurélie Filipetti, 38, a novelist and a legislator, was named culture minister. She had made public an account of being groped by Dominique Strauss-Kahn, the man **whom** many thought would be the Socialist candidate.

They say it should be *who* and not *whom* because the example here is that it's ultimately the verb being done by the subject that counts, not the "many thought" part (seems the verb gives priority to the subject rather than the other way around).

Comment: Please put the New York Times bit back where it was.

Comment: I think your example *If he had me do this from the beginning [something different might have happened* actually has ***less*** verbs than it should. Strictly speaking it should be *If he **would have** had me do this...* (normally contracted to *If **he'd have had** me do it...*, but I'm not ashamed to admit that if I were to "expand" it, I'd like as not come out with *If he **had have had** me do it...*).

Comment: Check out this grammar site on the Third Conditional. It's the best way to express your "If he had me doing this" example. http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/thirdconditional/menu.php

Comment: LOL, that would change its meaning quite a bit, though. I was hoping I could just use the "theoretical" "if he had it done" scenario as in _if I had  horses do all the work instead of cows_ versus _if I would have had horses to do all the work instead of cows_. Not sure if that makes sense with the past perfect tense... which feels awkward because "do" is simple present...

@TimWard Thanks for that, I'll check it out.

Comment: @LucidityofPower, no, the Third Conditional would express your statement this way: *If he **had** had me do this*... In information language, you'll hear people simply contract the noun and verb: *If he'd had me do this...* Now, you could also easily use the gerund form, *doing*, but that would only logically work if you are currently *doing* it.

Comment: @TimWard So, it WOULD work based on what you're saying then. These are third conditionals--and in this case, these sentences would be correct? _"If he had had my advising in this company"_ vs _"If he had had me advise in this company?"_

Comment: @LucidityofPower, CLOSE... but backwards. :)  *If he'd had **me** advising this company* or *If he'd had me advise this company* This sentence requires the object pronoun, not the possessive. If you flip it around, you could reword it and use the possessive: "My advising this company likely would have avoided this problem." That's grammatically correct, but no one speaks like that usually.

Comment: It's not grammatically incorrect to say “He said me being here was wonderful”—quite a lot of people would say just that. You can use either a pronoun in the oblique case or a possessive determiner as the subject of a gerund. What you seem to be missing, though, is that _have_ in the sense of ‘cause (someone) to (do something)’ **cannot be followed by a gerund**. It must be followed by an infinitive—and possessive determiners can never act as the subject of an infinitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are three different problems.

> 1. "He had me do this” vs “He had my doing this”

The former is correct. The latter is nonsensical.

> 2. He said me being here was wonderful.

Yes, logically, it should be ***my***, but no one ***ever*** says it like that. It's always ***me*** in this case. Go figure.

> 3. She had made public an account of being groped by Dominique Strauss-Kahn, the man whom many thought would be the Socialist candidate.

You're quite correct here. It should be **who**, since this is the nominative case. Some people who don't bother much about cases, though, reckon that "whom" sounds more sophisticated. That's the only explanation I can think of, and should anyone have a better one, I defy them to prove it.

**ADDENDUM (UPON POPULAR DEMAND):**

FumbleFingers' example, ***but the teacher obviously had my cheating in mind*** has nothing at all to do with any of this. My terminology is sketchy, but ...

**My teacher wouldn't have me cheating at the exam** means he'd kick my ass if he caught me in the act of cheating.

**My teacher had a problem with my cheating** means he knew I was a cheat *in general* and had a problem with it.

**He had me do this** means his purpose (which he achieved) was to coax, force, or trick ***me*** (not ***force my***, which would be nonsensical) into doing "this."

MORE ON THIS (from the OP's puzzled comment):

> ***If the teacher had my cheating on the exam, she'd fail me***. This works, right?

No, it doesn't.

One: To have someone [the accusative case] do something means to encourage, require, order, or force them to do it. It wouldn't make sense for the teacher to ask you to cheat and then fail you. I mean, shit happens; but generally teachers fail students because said students do something the teacher *didn't* ask them to do.

Two: "She had my cheating" doesn't make *any* sense unless it's the title of a book. As in "The teacher had *My Teaching*, by Umberto Eco, in her hands."

**If he had my doing the work**: This is wrong, and (attention! important information!) it is NOT related *in any way* to phrases like "Me being there brightened up the morons' lives." Nothing at all. Different rules, completely.

You ***can*** have me, or Linda, or John, do all the work for you.

You cannot, I emphasize, ***cannot***, have my, Linda's, or John's, do all the work for you. You can't have Linda's do all the work for you. You can only have Linda do all the work for you.

Please tell me if you still have a problem understanding this. We'll post a whole new question together and have another spirited crack at the son of a bitch.

Comment: It might be a bit convoluted, but I can't really see anything wrong with, say, *I got the cane for passing notes under the desk in last year's exams. I thought that was all forgotten by this year's exams, but the teacher obviously **had my cheating in mind,** because he made me sit at a desk well away from all the other pupils*. I think there has to be something along the lines of ***in mind*** there though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's an entirely different issue. And do _please_ put the NYTimes bit back in. You made the edit when I had already incorporated it in my answer.

Comment: Can you please explain why "He had me do this” is right and "He had my doing this" is wrong, yet it works in the example FumbleFingers gave? Why is "me do this" grammatically correct in this particular sentence? Please help.

Comment: @LucidityofPower: Okay, I'm going to add this to the answer. Hang on.

Comment: Okay, then what about a different example? "If the teacher had my cheating on the exam, she'd fail me." This works, right? And if it does, isn't it the same as "If he had my doing the work?" I fail to see the difference (grammatically) in these sentences:

_"He had my policing the perimeter"_ vs _"He had me policing the perimeter"_.....
_"She had my baking the cake"_ vs _"She had me bake the cake"_.....
_"If I had his presenting me in court, I would have won"_ vs _"If I had him present me in court, I would have won."_

Comment: @LucidityofPower: More explanations are in order, then. I need to leave; I'll be back in an hour and explain it all to you. Be patient.

Comment: I would never say "He said me being here was wonderful."  It would always be "my", if I used that sentence structure.  Though I would likely choose other words.

Comment: @HotLicks: As I mention in the second edit, the correct phraseology would be "Me being there brightened up the morons' lives." Without the "he said" part. He said, she said. Who cares.

Comment: Wait. In this sentence, _"She had my cheating" doesn't make any sense unless it's the title of a book,_ it seems a lot more semantics related than grammar. Grammatically it's correct, though, no?

Comment: It's not really any more logical to say ‘my being there’ than ‘me being there’. Both are perfectly logical and in common use. Doesn't matter if there's a “he said” part or not.

Comment: @LucidityofPower Grammatically, yes, it's correct _strictu sensu_. But it means “She was in possession of the cheating that belonged to me”, i.e., it is completely parallel to “She had my coat”. If the intention is for it to mean “She made me cheat”, then it is not grammatically correct.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In *“Her boss always calling her was the problem”* (or the longer *“It was her boss always calling her at night that was the trouble"*), it’s clear that *her boss* is the subject of the non-finite verb *calling her*. To me that's the same as *“Him always calling her was the problem”*, and while I know determiners can apply to an entire gerund phrase, *“His always calling her was the problem”* really isn't how people naturally say that—and *“His constant calling of her at night was the problem”* is worse still. Oblique subjects of non-finite verb phrases seem here to stay.

Comment: @tchrist I don’t quite follow you there. Are you agreeing or disagreeing with me? The most natural way to phrase your example would be “His/him constantly calling her at night was the problem”; I don’t really have a preference between the two. Neither works very well with _always_, though, I agree.

Comment: **He had me doing** the laundry at night. =OK//He had my doing the laundry at night. BUZZER. I really don't understand how this answer could have gotten three points when the first point misses the point of the question.....

Answer (score 1):

From Practical English Usage:

> Let, make, see, hear, feel, watch, notice, have, and sometimes know and help are followed by object + infinitive without to.

So, 'I had you do' is correct. 'Had you to do', sounds wrong to me. 'Had you doing' doesn't really sound that bad, although I think it would be incorrect.

I have checked in youglish and 'have me doing' has 500ish videos with it, whereas have me do has 5500. Many were used in the same sense, so I guess it is possible although strange.